# Is there a way to display pop-up messages in slack?

Tags: chatbot, slack-api

I am developing a chat bot with slack. I want to display a pop-up message with certain editable fields in slack as a response to query. How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pop up message feature per se, but you can show a modal window called [Dialog](https://api.slack.com/dialogs) with editable fields as response to a query.